# Does the CreateObject method follow any specific syntax?

Tags: vba

For instance, at first I thought that what went in the parentheses was the library and class separated by a period (Ex: `"Scripting.Dictionary"`, `"Scripting.FileSystemObject"`.  However, when you use it for internet explorer it is `"InternetExplorer.Application"` instead of `"SHDocVw.InternetExplorer"`.  Is the syntax not standard and something you just need to look up every time?  I will use early binding anyways but I'm just curious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The string used as a parameter to `CreateObject()` is what's known as a *programmatic identifier* or `"ProgId"`. COM classes identify themselves using a `CLSID`, or what is essentially a `GUID`. But rather than having to remember and type the `CLSID` for the `FileSystemObject` COM class whenever you need to instantiate the COM object (which is `{0D43FE01-F093-11CF-8940-00A0C9054228}`, by the way), COM allows for the specification of a `ProgId` string.

You can examine the contents of the `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID` registry key to see all COM classes available on your PC. Here's the `CLSID` for the `FileSystemObject` class, showing the `ProgID`:

[image]

Tools like OleView or NirSoft's [ActiveXHelper](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/axhelper.html) make finding `ProgId`s much easier. Other languages require you to jump through hoops to create COM objects. But the VB family of languages is "COM aware" and provides the necessary utilities to easily create and work with COM components without having to worry about `IIDs`, `CLSIDs`, `Type Libraries`, and other "COM" mumbo jumbo. In VB, when you add a `"Reference"`, you're referencing a `Type Library`. When you call `CreateObject(<string>)`, you're telling Windows to look up the `CLSID` of the COM class with a `ProgId` of `<string>`. They're just simpler, cleaner ways to interface with the COM world.

To (try to) answer your question, a `ProgId` can really be anything the creator of the COM object chooses. It's typically `"<COM Library>.<COM Class>"` but that's not always the case. Often version numbers are included. `"MSMXL2.DOMDocument.6.0"`, for example, includes a version number for both the library and the class. Other times, there's no library at all (`CreateObject("htmlfile")`, for example). So, unfortunately, there's no perfect standard here.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you are accessing the library.
NOTE: This will work in Visual Basic or VBScript

```
fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
```

Scripting is the name of the type library, and FileSystemObject is the name of the object of which you want to create an instance.

If you have the library referenced, you don't need to go through the scripting library.
NOTE: This will only work in Visual Basic.

```
Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
```

Comment: yeah, I understand the difference between that.  I meant why does the CreateObject syntax vary between different objects (not all of them follow the "Library.Class"  definition

Comment: It's the name of the object. Regardless of the path you have to reference it.